# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: springfox.documentation.common.ClassPresentInClassPathCondition

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I am trying to add Swagger to my project https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

I got 4.3 paragraph in the tutorial above and when I run my application, I got some errors.

This I added to my `pom.xml` :

```
    <dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, I added config class :

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}
}
```

And when I run my project, I got :

[image: STACKTRACE1]
[image: STACKTRACE2]

Comment: are you using @EnableSwagger2? and also try to use `io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0`

Comment: @Marco I added annotation EnableSwagger2 to my SwaggerConfig file and I don't have any errors but in the Swagger guide that I attached by the link in the post says that after configuring you should go to this url : 'http://localhost:8080/spring-security-rest/api/v2/api-docs' and when I got this url, I have nothing, maybe I did something wrong..

Comment: To verify that Springfox is working, we can visit this URL in our browser:

http://localhost:8080/spring-security-rest/api/v2/api-docs

The result is a JSON response with a large number of key-value pairs, which is not very human readable. Fortunately, Swagger provides Swagger UI for this purpose.

It is in the Swagger guide but I don't have it after go to this url..

Comment: Did you tried to hit http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs?

Comment: @Marco Yes, but I got HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Comment: try to adding     `.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors
                        .basePackage("your.package"))` and remove `.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())`

Answer (score 7):

I removed the following dependency from pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

For me it worked

Comment: That removes the Swagger page which is probably not what you want.

Comment: What is the solution - if we don't want to remove the swagger? - because removing the above removes swagger page

Answer (score 0):

I came around this error while upgrading spring-boot v2.1.1 to v3.0.5. So here I upgraded `springfox-swagger2` and `springfox-swagger-ui` both to the same version 3.0.0